# React-native fetch. CertPathValidatorException error

Tags: android, ssl, react-native

The complete error

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

My target platform is Android. The problem I suppose is in self-signed ssl certificate on the backend. And I can't change it. So the question. Is there any way to install this certificate to my device (trust it) so I can make fetch requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pinch package.